# .htaccess - rewriting /path.php to /path/ and not 404-ing files in sub-directories

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

Firstly, I apologise. This topic has been rehashed repeatedly, (I know. I read them.) But for whatever reason, my case is either odd, or I'm breaking something else in the .htaccess.

**Objective**

1. Hide PHP file extensions,
2. 301 any attempt at getting to them to their masquerading path,
3. Allow PHP files within sub-directories to be *actually* referenced,
4. Rewrite underscores in file names as slashes (/) so they appear to be nested. (**edit:** or translate / in the URL to be _'s in the file - unless the directory exists.)

... 3 & 4 are the kickers.

The following code is the .htaccess I've been using prior to this...

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## Imagine Some Code here ##

# Redirect to domain with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Ensure all directory URLs have a trailing slash.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried adding the following snippets where I noted.

```
RewriteRule    ^$    /index.php    [L]
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_/]*)/$    /$1/index.php    [L]
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_/]*)\.(html|htm)$    /$1.php    [L]
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_/]*)$    /$1.php    [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and the most success was:

```
# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ https://www.actual_domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://www.actual_domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

That last one was pretty good actually, however, I couldn't access php files at all in any format (with/without extension) in sub-directories. And all attempts at adding in something that handled requirement 4 just didn't work.

As much as I would love for someone to just go BAM, done. Use and enjoy. I would really like to understand what is going wrong too.

Thanks in advance.

-- edit --

As requested by misorude, the following URLs are examples.

**URL:** actual_domain.com.au/blog - **Reads file:** /blog.php

**URL:** actual_domain.com.au/path/to-file - **Reads file:** /path_to-file.php

**URL:** actual_domain.com.au/dir/file - **Reads file:** /dir/file.php

With the last example (/dir/) the dir directory exists. With the /path/ one, it isn't a directory.

Now, as for my wording for objective 3, I have found that the .htaccess code that I have tried appears to prevent anything physically in a sub-directory returns 404. (case in point, that last example above referencing /dir/)

And lastly, with respect to the rewriting of / or _, the file contains the _ and I'd like it to present as a / in the url.

-- edit --

I've managed to do this:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} path_to-file\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /path/to-file [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^path/to-file/?$ /path_to-file.php [L,NC]
```

... which works checking the headers, but 404's in practice. It is also hard coding a specific path. Which isn't really what I wanted to do.

Now, the failing in practice. 
Using: https://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php
with the url: https://actual_domain.com.au/path/to-file

I get this:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found =>
Cache-Control => private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma => no-cache
Content-Type => text/html
Content-Length => 618
Date => Mon, 12 Aug 2019 06:27:16 GMT
Server => LiteSpeed
Location => https://actual_domain.com.au/path_to-file.php
Alt-Svc => quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,39,43,44"
Connection => close
```

You can see that the location redirection works, but it still gives 404 - even though going to the redirected path works! :(

Thoughts?

Comment: Please provide example URLs for the different cases, and what you actually want to happen with them. What does 3., “actually referenced” mean? There you want to allow the `.php` extension again, or what?

Comment: _“Rewrite underscores in file names as slashes (/) so they appear to be nested.”_ - so actually the other way around then? Rewrite slashes in the incoming request to underscores - so that `/foo/bar/baz` gets mapped onto `/foo_bar_baz.php`?

Comment: Thank you for your responses @misorude - I have updated the question with information / clarifications.

Comment: `with respect to the rewriting of / or _, the file contains the _ and I'd like it to present as a / in the url` - What is problem in showing `_` to client/browser?

Comment: @anubhava - I'm trying to keep the files in the root, but still have it visually nested in a "sub-directory", so that the path shows it's parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have your .htaccess as this:

```
# turn directory slash on
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

# add www to a domain name taking care of both http and https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# remove .php from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# ignore all files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# add .php extension
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Replace / by _ recursively
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1_$2
```

Make sure when you test, you only have these rules and you test from a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Oooooh! we're getting somewhere :) Issues: **1)** actual files (ie: `/dir/file`) isn't working. The .php isn't being applied internally I presume. (`/dir/file.php` is the actual file)  and   **2)** I had to reverse the order of the last two code blocks to make it work.

Comment: The HTTP Header checking site tells me that `https://actual_domain.com.au/dir/file.php` redirects to `https://actual_domain.com.au/dir/file`, but that `https://actual_domain.com.au/dir/file` doesn't load `https://actual_domain.com.au/dir/file.php`

Comment: I had tested these rules on my local apache/.htaccess and tested it again. For me `www.localhost/dir/file.php` got redirected to `www.localhost/dir/file` and it correctly loaded `www.localhost/dir/file.php`. Order of rules must be as I have written in answer. Make sure there is no other code in your .htaccess when you test it.

Comment: This assumes that .htaccess is placed right in the directory where `DocumentRoot` is pointed to. Check your `DocumentRoot` setting in server as well.

Comment: This is a typical cPanel account from what I can tell. The website files are in the public_html. So I presume the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} should refer to that. (& the .htaccess is in the same directory)

Comment: ok try replacing `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`

Comment: Nope. That didn't work either.  :( `https://actual_domain.com.au/dir/file.php` still 404's even though it's literally there in that path.

Comment: I assume it's because it's one level away from the root? as `https://actual_domain.com.au/file.php` works properly.

Comment: Try my updated code. Make sure there is no other code.

Comment: Hi - Ok, I _think_ that's got it working. I just have to make sure that the things I believe are JS errors are actually JS errors (it's using AJAX). I'll get back to you. :)

Comment: Ok, that's 99% working. There is another issue, but I think that's a conceptual mistake I've made during this. I will attend to that in JS. Thank you so much for your help @anubhava! :) I really appreciate your time and effort.